# Make images larger in HTML with no blur

Tags: html, image

I have been messing around with some new ideas in Javascript, but I'm not very good at making extremely detailed images in Paint, Paint.NET, etc. The problem is when I have a 64 * 64 image or an 8 * 8 and I want it to display 640 * 640 or 16 * 16; the images get blurry. I've seen many other forums and things were people ask this question or a similar one, but I'm relatively new to this and don't want to make the image larger in photoshop or whatever. On a similar note, can I display only part of an image at one time but have a larger image than shown, so that I don't have to make multiple images of the same thing?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this CSS attribute on your `img` helps:

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

I found it in this blog post:
https://css-tricks.com/keep-pixelated-images-pixelated-as-they-scale/

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled here and this totally fixed my problem of displaying tiny bitmaps.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your images get blurry when enlarged is because it is a rasterised graphic (pixel based image) and not a vector graphic (path based image).

When you try to enlarge the rasterised image, the pixels expand in size too which leads to the lower quality/blurry result (also referred to as 'pixelation').

> The difference between vector and raster graphics is that raster graphics are composed of pixels, while vector graphics are composed of paths.
>
> Source: http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/vector_and_raster_graphics

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it bigger without the picture becoming blurry. You are using a raster image. A raster image is an image that is made up of pixels. a color is assigned to each individual pixel. If you enlarge the picture. Each pixel will just be scaled so that it takes up more space on the screen. This will cause the image to appear blurry.

Here's an example:

```
rrr
rbr
rrr
```

"r" is a red pixel and "b" is a blue pixel. The dimensions are 3*3.

If you try to make the dimensions larger than 3*3, lets say 6*6, this happens.:

```
rrrrrr
rrrrrr
rrbbrr
rrbbrr
rrrrrr
rrrrrr
```

With the image was enlarged, each pixel just became bigger. In the larger image, each 2*2 square was originally 1 pixel in the original image. Now with this example, the new image wasn't blurry because it was just a square. But if you have a more complex image, it becomes blurry.

To fix your problem, use a vector image. A vector image is different from a raster image. Instead of being made up of pixels, it is made of shapes and lines and stuff like that. Each shape has a width, height, x coordinate, and y coordinate. Some shapes have even more variables. Because of this, vector images can be zoomed in indefinitely without becoming blurry. Sometimes when you zoom in on a vector image the quality even becomes better!

Here's an example:

```
rrr
rbr
rrr
```

Again, "r" is a red pixel and "b" is a blue pixel. Let's say this image has a width of 500. But you are zoomed out so far that it appears as a 3*3 square on the screen. In the center of the image is a blue circle. Now it doesn't look like a circle because it only takes up one pixel on the screen. So it looks like  square. The circle has a fixed radius. and it is located in the center of the image.

Let's zoom in:

```
rrrrr
rrbrr
rbbbr
rrbrr
rrrrr
```

The image still has dimensions of 500*500. It is just zoomed in farther so that it takes up 5*5 on the screen. But the circle looks less like a square and more like a cross. and a 3*3 cross looks more like a circle than a 1*1 square.

The farther you zoom in, the more the image will look like a circle. But since you are using a raster image, enlarging it will result in a blurry picture.

**To fix your problem use vector images instead of raster images.**

Answer (score 0):

For any form of res-sizing images, you will need a Vector-formatted image. 
Vector formats are of the following:

- CGM
- Gerber format (RS-274X)
- SVG

[Image File Formats - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use vector based graphics (svg), not raster bitmaps (jpg, png, gif).
Good thing about SVG is you can add CSS and JS to interact with it in a webpage.
Check this article on how [to interface with the SVG](http://tumba.solutions/blog/svg)

Comment: The only difference from the vector image to the raster image in your example is that the pixels are clearly shown and it's not smooth. I'm fine with it being pixelated, it just seems that the pictures seem to be getting blurry when resized, and not pixels anymore.